# show menu when click on a button in a UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am new in universal apps world,so I have a web menu that I want to do the same for my universal app,please What is called the component in universal store apps that let me show a Menu when I click on a Button like this:

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: Have a look at the Flyout Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the flyout control.
This would look like that:

```
<Button Content="Trier par : Nom">
   <Button.Flyout>
      <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
         <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Nom" />
            <Button Content="Categorie" />
            <Button Content="Ville" />
            <Button Content="Editeur" />
         </StackPanel>
      </Flyout>
   </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

For further information have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.flyout).

Comment: thanks croxy for your reply,and the Click function for the Button Trier should show the Flyout menu ? :)

Comment: Yes, the event to open the flyout is automatically attached to the button. Therefore you haven't to do anything else there to open the flyout.